# Accessing Previous output while operator chaining in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

How to access the resulting output value to perform an upcoming operation for example:

```
scala> List(1,4,3,4,4,5,6,7)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7)

scala> res0.removeDuplicates.slice(0, ???.size -2)
```

In the above line, i need to perform slice operation after removing duplicates. To do this, how to access output of `.removeDuplicate()`, so that i can use it to find `size` for slice operation.

I need to perform this in a single step. Not in multiple steps like:

```
scala> res0.removeDuplicates
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7)

scala> res1.slice(0, res1.size -2)
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3, 5)
```

I want to access intermediate results in the final operation. `removeDuplicates()` is just an example.

`list.op1().op2().op3().finalop()` here i want to access: output of `op1`,`op2`,`op3` in `finalop`

Comment: Scala's standard library provides [List#distinct](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#distinct:Repr), so `removeDuplicates` may likely be unnecessary.

Comment: Example: `List(1,4,3,4,4,5,6,7).distinct` == `List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7)`

Comment: You want to access *all* intermediate results? Or is the result of `op3` enough?

Comment: i need all of it. Please mention if you know to access only op3(i.e previous) it will be helpful too

Answer (score 4):

Wrapping into into an `Option` may be one option (no pun intended):

```
val finalResult = Some(foo).map { foo => 
  foo.op1(foo.stuff)
}.map { foo => 
  foo.op2(foo.stuff)
}.map { foo => 
  foo.op3(foo.stuff)
}.get.finalOp
```

You can make the wrapping part implicit to make it a little nicer:

```
object Tapper {
  implicit class Tapped[T] extends AnyVal(val v: T) {
     def tap[R](f: T => R) = f(v)
  }
}

import Tapper._
val finalResult = foo
 .tap(f => f.op1(f.stuff))
 .tap(f => f.op2(f.stuff))
 .tap(f => f.finalOp(f.stuff))
```

Comment: If you want access to the output of every step at the final step, you will probably also need a `flatTap` ;)

Answer (score 4):

With **for comprehension** it is possible to compose operations in quite readable way with ability to access intermediate results:

```
val res = for {
  ls1 <- Option(list.op1)
  ls2 = ls1.op2()           // Possible to access list, ls1
  ls3 = ls2.op3()           // Possible to access list, ls1, ls2
} yield ls4.finalOp()       // Possible to access list, ls1, ls2, ls3
```

For example:

```
scala> val ls = List(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
ls: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

for {
  ls1 <- Option(ls.map(_ * 2))
  ls2 = ls1.map(_ + ls1.size)
  ls3 = ls2.filter(_ < ls1.size + ls2.size)
} yield ls3.sum

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res15: Option[Int] = Some(72)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not need to know the length if you use `dropRight`:

```
scala> val a = List(1,4,3,4,4,5,6,7)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7)

scala> a.dropRight(2)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

So do this: `res0.removeDuplicates.dropRight(2)`

Comment: i want to access intermediate results in the final operation. `removeDuplicates()` is just an example.`list.op1().op2().op3().finalop()` here i want to access: output of `op1`,`op2`,`op3` in `finalop`

Comment: @codeSteward What you're asking for in this comment is completely different from your question. You want to generically be able to access the previous result in the current method invocation?

Comment: No, `removeDuplicates()` is an example of an operation (op1, op2, ...). I just generalized it.

Comment: You can do that by saving information from op1() into a ResultWrapper that gets passed from op1 to op2, etc. So don't just pass Result; pass ResultWrapper, which contains the intermediate data you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need it in one function, you can write a custom `foldLeft`, something like this:

```
var count = 0
val found = new HashSet()
res0.foldLeft(List[Int]()) { (z, i) =>
    if(!found.contains(i)){
        if(count < 4){
            z :+ i
            found += i
            count += 1
        }
    }
}
```

However I don't really see the problem in chaining calls like in `res0.removeDuplicates.slice`. One benefit of functional programming is that our compiler can optimize in situations like this where we just want a certain behavior and don't want to specify the implementation.

Comment: I used `removeDuplicates()` as just an example. essentially i want to use all previous operation's output in the current operation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to process some data through a series of transformations: someData -> op1 -> op2 -> op3 -> finalOp. However, inside op3, you would like to have access to intermediate results from the processing done in op1. The key here is to pass to the next function in the processing chain all the information that will be required downstream.

Let's say that your input is `xs: Seq[String]` and op1 is of type `(xs: Seq[String]) => Seq[String]`. You want to modify op1 to return `case class ResultWrapper(originalInputLength: Int, deduplicatedItems: Seq[String], somethingNeededInOp5: SomeType)`. If all of your ops pass along what the other ops need down the line, you will get what you need. It's not very elegant, because there is coupling between your ops: the upstream needs to save the info that the downstream needs. They are not really "different operations" any more at this point.

One thing you can do is to use a Map[A,B] as your "result wrapper". This way, there is less coupling between ops, but less type safety as well.